# Proper way to find records for a certain foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two Models called User and Membership.
User has_many :memberships
Membership belongs_to :user

What is the proper way to modify MembershipsController's index method to set @memberships to all the memberships there are for the user "session[:user_id]"?

I tried something like:
@memberships = Membership.find(:all, :conditions => ["user_id = ?", session[:user_id]] )

but then Rails is Selecting from users instead of memberships:

```
Rendering memberships/index
  ←[4;35;1mUser Columns (3.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSHOW FIELDS FROM `users`←[0m
  ←[4;36;1mUser Load (1.0ms)←[0m   ←[0;1mSELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) LIMIT
  ←[4;35;1mCACHE (0.0ms)←[0m   ←[0mSELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1←[0m
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user_id wasn't being set correctly.

script/console:

```
>> Membership.find(:first, :conditions => "user_id = 1")
=> nil
```

Logs:

```
Completed in 19ms (View: 9, DB: 6) | 200 OK [http://localhost/memberships]
  [4;36;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSET NAMES 'utf8'[0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0[0m
  [4;36;1mUser Columns (2.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSHOW FIELDS FROM `users`[0m
  [4;35;1mSQL (0.0ms)[0m   [0mSHOW TABLES[0m
  [4;36;1mUser Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`id` = 1) [0m
  [4;35;1mMembership Load (1.0ms)[0m   [0mSELECT * FROM `memberships` WHERE (user_id = 1) LIMIT 1[0m
  [4;36;1mMembership Load (0.0ms)[0m   [0;1mSELECT * FROM `memberships` WHERE (user_id = 1) LIMIT 1[0m
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `session[:user_id]` represent? Are you trying to roll your own authentication system?

There are a [number of authentication solutions](http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/02/21/rails-2-3-authentication-comparison) that can handle the ins and outs of that for you.

To answer your question though, you probably want to be making use of the [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) you've set up between the two models:

```
def index
  @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
  @memberships = @user.memberships if @user
end
```

Using an application-wide authentication system (whether of your own-making or using a library) this would most likely be simplified to:

```
def index
  @memberships = current_user.memberships
end
```

where `current_user` is a method defined in `ApplicationController` that returns the currently logged in user and the `index` action has a [`before_filter`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter) that ensures that the user is logged in.